# Use EXPECT_CALL on local object of function?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock

Is there a way to use EXPECT_CALL on a local object of a function?

For example:

```
template<class T>
std::string doSomethingWithTheCar()
{
    T car;
    return "the color of the car is: " + car.color();
}

class Car
{
public:
    std::string color()
    {
        return "green";
    }
};

class MockCar
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(color, std::string());
};

TEST(MockLocalObject, doSomethingWithCarTest) {
    EXPECT_CALL(car, color())
        .WillOnce(Return("red"));

    std::string color = doSomethingWithTheCar<MockCar>();
    EXPECT_EQ(color, "red");
}
```

Due to the template I can control if the real Car object will be used or the MockCar. But is there a way to use `EXPECT_CALL` on this?

Comment: In general - no. But your question is not precise enough, I am sure that there is an easy solution to your problem, though. You can expect call on a mock class method, you can expect call on a `testing::MockFunction<ReturnType(ArgsType)>;`. Try to explain, what exactly do you want to achieve. Provide the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Ptaq666: thank you for your answer. I didn't know MockFunction, but I'll look into it. I added the classes and a test, how I want it to be. 

Is there any complete overview about all of GMocks functions? I have not found an api documentation yet.

Comment: Sure, here: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock/docs

Comment: Oh, the CheatSheet is more helpful than the other docs in this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
class AbstractCar {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractCar() = default;
    virtual std::string color() = 0;
};

class Car: public AbstractCar {
public:
    ~Car() override = default;
    std::string color() override {
        return "green";
    }
};

class MockCar: public AbstractCar {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(color, std::string());
};

std::string doSomethingWithTheCar(AbstractCar* car)  // or even better - use std::shared_ptr
{
    return "the color of the car is: " + car->color();
}

TEST(MockLocalObject, doSomethingWithCarTest) {
    auto car = new MockCar;
    EXPECT_CALL(*car, color()).WillOnce(Return("red"));

    std::string color = doSomethingWithTheCar(car);
    // this test will fail, because actual string is:
    // "the color of the car is: red"
    EXPECT_EQ(color, "red");
    delete car;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already use this. But the original function does not have a parameter. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why can't you change the function to accept the parameter? Without any kind of dependency injection (like `doSomethingWithTheCar(const T& car)`, or `doSomethingWithTheCar(CarFactory* factory)` ), it is probably impossible to mock the behavior of your `car` inside the considered function (or the function return value in any way).

Comment: I can, I just wanted to know if there is any way I may not know. C++ is just way too big, so I get surprised from time to time. Thanks a lot. I'll re-think my code structure. Perhaps I can change a bit here and there